# Creating UML diagrams: 3-player Chess

Tags: uml

I have to create UML diagram for 3-player chess. I have an existing project for a 2-player chess game which is working fine. I have to extend it to 3-player chess. So my question is, will moving from 2-player chess to 3-player chess change my class diagram? Or, will it just change the behavioral diagrams of UML?

Its going to be like this vat19.com/item/three-man-chess. and my package structure in the project is like this: 
MainApplet class 
Pieces class inherited by different pieces like king,queen,rook,etc. 
Move class for deciding the movements throughout the board.

So my question still remains , does my class diagram have to have a huge change? I feel the class diagram wouldnt change much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what three player chess looks like.  I've only played with two players.

Comment: Please post your existing model.

Comment: For sure, a chess game with 3 players is as similar to a normal chess like apples match pears.

Comment: Voting to close because the question is unclear without the existing class diagram and a reference to 3-player chess.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about three player chess that uses a non-traditional board, then yes, your `ChessBoard` entity will certainly need changed. Other changes will vary based on which variant of three player chess you choose.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-player_chess#Hexagonal_boards_with_quadrilateral_cells

Comment: Its going to be like this https://www.vat19.com/item/three-man-chess.  and my package structure in the project is like this:

MainApplet class
Pieces class inherited by different pieces like king,queen,rook,etc.
Move class for deciding the movements throughout the board.

So my question still remains , does my class diagram have to have a huge change? I feel the class diagram wouldnt change much.

Comment: Why do you refuse to post your existing diagram?